# UITableViewController: Update cell from DOWNLOADING to DONE

Tags: ios, swift

My table has two cell types

- Downloading -- includes a `UIProgressView`
- Done -- shows the actual thing we downloaded

So far, the table view controller requests a download from `Lesson.downloadLesson(25)` and receives a `Progress` object which it assigns to the UIProgressView. This is nice because the screen will update as that file download happens (actually there's a lot of steps but that magic is hidden behind `Progress`).

At some point progress will reach 100% and the table view controller should redraw that cell in the DONE style to show details from the downloaded content.

**What mechanism is appropriate for the table view controller to learn that the operation is complete?**

Comment: [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) should help

Answer (score 1):

Your each download task must encapsulate a callback (completion handler method) which should trigger the redraw of the cell on which the download task is completed. Instead of reloading the entire UITableView, you should reload only the cell/row which has completed the download task.

Let me know if you need any more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using URLSession for download files then

```
// Here you get finish download notification. 
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    // 1 save file at track index(get from original download URL) and do your other app changes  
    //... save 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // 2 Reload row of trackIndex
      self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: trackIndex, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
    })
}
```

You no need to take separate cell for display progress and donw download button. In `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`

```
// Check local file exist or not
let downloaded = localFileExistsForTrack(track)

// Set UI accordingly 
var showDownloadControls = false
if let download = activeDownloads[track.previewUrl!] {
  showDownloadControls = true

  cell.progressView.progress = download.progress
  cell.progressLabel.text = (download.isDownloading) ? "Downloading..." : "Paused"
}
cell.progressView.hidden = !showDownloadControls
cell.progressLabel.hidden = !showDownloadControls
```

Check very good example for this task [nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started)